# How to use TypeScript in existing ES6 based ReactJS application?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I already have a react application which is developed in ES6(.jsx) which is a huge project. I want to do my further development in typescript to use the luxury of typescript.
The problem I have is I can't redevelop my entire project in typescript.
I just want to write new files with typeScript.

Comment: I found a very good article(https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/). let's see how good it is..?

Answer (score 0):

I had to just upgrade my babel version to babel7 using [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration).
Babel7 has support of .ts|.tsx. 
Then I followed [this](https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/) link to make TS work.

For a completed solution I have written an [article on medium](https://medium.com/@aliusmaanali13/use-typescript-in-existing-es6-based-reactjs-application-e8911e11b104)

Answer (score -2):

**To add TypeScript to a Create React App project, first install it:**

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

## or

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

**Next, rename any file to be a TypeScript file (e.g. src/index.js to src/index.tsx) and restart your development server!**

Type errors will show up in the same console as the build one.